# Find the equation of price - supply ,price - demand

Tags: linear-algebra, economics, slope

I have a question as homework
I solved it using  online calculators but didn't understated it fully, even form my teacher

[image]

Here the solution form Online calculator

[image]

https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/algebra-1/line-calculator/?lt=p&px=16.5&py=11.6&qx=15.3&qy=10.9&s=&ppx=&ppy=&steps=on

My question is that when I calculated by hand I got it wrong why is that ?

here my hand  calculation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If $p=mx+b$ then I would have thought the slope was the change in price divided by the change in quantity so in this case $$\dfrac{11.6-10.9}{165045-152975}=\dfrac{0.7}{12070}\approx 0.000058$$

You seem to have lost a factor of $10000$ and divided the change in quantity by the change in price